# Celery Beat - How to invoke a periodic task manually?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

In our production environment, we have a Celery beat configured to perform periodic tasks according to the frequency.

My question is, is there a way for me to start the task that was meant to run at specific time right now?

Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated.

I tried to add the periodic task using `app.add_periodic_task` from python interpreter, but it didn't work.

I am looking for some help to run any specific scheduled task at that moment either from Python interpreter or celery command line.

Comment: Are you trying to cancel the periodic (beat) triggering and run manually instead or in addition? Can you add your effort (code) here please?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I tried the below steps
>>> from celery import Celery
>>> from celery.schedules import crontab
>>> app = Celery('celeryapp')
>>> app.config_from_object('celeryapp.celeryconfig')
>>> app.add_periodic_task(10, cleanup)

But here the problem is, it is adding another task with the frequency of once in every 10 minutes.

Comment: Continuation to my previous comment
---------------------------------------
My requirement is that it not add any new tasks or terminate any ongoing periodic tasks; instead, it must immediately invoke the periodic tasks without interfering with their frequency. 
For example, my task is scheduled to run once every 24 hours; it must continue to do so. Additionally, I should be able to run it dynamically from either Celery or Python interpreter.

Comment: is `cleanup` a celery task? can you add the signature of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this through following two scenarios.

1. Connect to the related docker instance container where the Celery beat is hosted and run the below commands in Python interpreter

   > > > from mymodule.celerybeat import cleanup
   > > > cleanup.apply_async()
   > > > <AsyncResult: afd71a7f-2246-4946-8572-267f3494df31>
2. Using the Celery command line through subcommand `call`

   celery -A myceleryapp:app call mymodule.celerybeat.cleanup

**Note:** Here myceleryapp is the app name and cleanup is the periodic task.